# Bootstrap carousel slides height changing when sliding bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have been asked to work on the following website by my boss: [2tec.club](http://2tec.club)

The site has been built using Wordpress which I am not an expert in, I have access to only the admin dashboard.

The slider at the top has a strange bug, as you can see, every time the slide changes onto the next slide ,that particular slide for a brief second changes its height. This causes the content to be pushed down briefly which is extremely annoying for the visitors. 
**NOTE: this only happens on larger devices. It seems fine on my phone.**

I have tried using the Chrome developer tools to change the CSS rules with no luck. I cannot for the life of me figure this one out. Can someone please be kind enough to offer their help. If so it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove the `slide` class from your `#myCarousel` the problem goes away.

There's a number of other issues however. It seems as though you are including bootstrap twice, once for version 3.3.2 and once for version 3.3.6.

You also mention that you're using bootstrap carousel, but you have a `carousel.js` that appears to be owl-carousel.

So if you're using bootstrap carousel, and you also have owl-carousel - there is the potential for unknown conflicts.

You should review all the files you're including when you get the chance.

Comment: it worked, but seem don't have the transitions, I tried to resize the images with the same size and it worked too.

Answer (score 0):

your theme is uploading the style.css before bootstrap.css... so its not able to overwrite the changes to bootstrap..

if you r not familiar with coding the easiest solution would be to use bigger images. at this moment your image size is 960 X 295... change it to 1200 X 368.. point is increase the width of the image...

let me know if it works